# How to handle SSL certificate for Firefox, Chrome and IE browsers using Selenium 3.4.0 standalone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My application has both http and https ssl certificate. To handle https link using Selenium 3.4.0 I have used following code for firefox. Firefox browser is opening, but it is showing 'Secure Connection Failed'

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\vidhya.r\\Desktop\\Automation\\Jars\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile pro = new FirefoxProfile();
pro.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(pro);
driver.get("https://192.168.8.115:7077/final/#!");
```

Comment: Please see these links.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578023/using-personal-ssl-certificates-with-webdriver-selenium-2-0/10017559#10017559 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868708/how-to-use-ssl-certificates-in-selenium-web-driver

Comment: Above method didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution will definitely work for your chrome browser.

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get(applicationURL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```