# How to detect SSL certificate information using Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to collect some data, and one of the requirements is to get SSL Certificate information like the issuer, expiry date, mixed content, etc.

Is there a way in Selenium to get this information?

I am using Selenium with Ruby.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless'])
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
driver.get 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

After that, I am clueless as to how to get any information of the SSL certificates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868708/how-to-use-ssl-certificates-in-selenium-web-driver ?

Comment: Code trials please.

Comment: @Marged That is a way to use certificate at my end, what I want is to read certificate of the address I am opening.

Comment: @DebanjanB I didn't get you.

Comment: @Shobhit I am asking about your code trials which you have tried to solve the issue

Comment: Paste your code here, The problem is, you might have opened the browser with general mode, but you need to open your browser with your default profile or from your customized profile. So include your code part with your answer.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Added code

Comment: Is it working then?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Nope. I am clueless as to where to even look. Searching is not yielding anything. All I am getting is how to ignore SSL certificates.

Comment: You still haven't loaded your profile.

Comment: Your given code is not loading the profile, it's loading the general.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Okay, let me add that and update with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look in [this](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security/#type-CertificateSecurityState) it might be helpful.

Adding to it Chrome Performance Logging records `Network.responseReceived` event from which we can get information about securitydetails in Network.Response.

Ref: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-Response

Comment: Have you got any other solution? @Shobhit

Comment: It will be really helpful if anyone can add a complete working code? I did not understand how to use the `Network.responseReceived` event and extract certificate details.